# Having trouble displaying my number using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I have to convert from decimal to binary and it requires at least 3 functions and it has to be displayed in HTML. This is what I've got so far and can't figure out how to make it display properly?

```js
// Prompt user for number between 1-1000
let input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 1000", "50"));

function store() {
let quotient = [];
let answer = quotient.reverse();
return answer;
}
function check() {
    while (input != 0) {
        if (input < 1000 && input % 2 != 0) {
            return quotient.push("1");
            input = input / 2;
        }
        else if (input < 1000 && input % 2 == 0) {
            return quotient.push("0");
            input = input / 2;
        }
    }
}
function display() {
    document.getElementById("displayNumber").innerHTML = answer;
}
display();
```

```html
<h1 id="displayNumber"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fixed script, I hope this helps.

```
   function check(input, quotient) {
       while (input != 0) {
        if (input < 1000 && input % 2 != 0) {
            quotient.push("1");
            input = parseInt(input / 2);
        }else if (input < 1000 && input % 2 == 0) {
            quotient.push("0");
            input = parseInt(input / 2);
        }
    }
}

function display() {
    let input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 1000", "50"));
    let quotient = [];
    check(input, quotient);
    let answer = quotient.reverse().join('');
    document.getElementById("displayNumber").innerHTML = answer;
}
display();
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are just creating the function `store` and `check` but not actually calling them.

However, if all you are wanting to do is to display the input as binary, you can use the `toString` function, passing in the base you desire.

Im not sure what you want to display if the number is outside of the range 1-1000. So I just put "Invalid input". You can add some more checks for if it is NAN ect

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

   <h1 id="displayNumber"></h1>
   <script>
     // Prompt user for number between 1-1000
     let input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 1000", "50"));
     
     function display() {
       if (input < 1 || input > 1000) {
         document.getElementById("displayNumber").innerHTML = "Invalid input";
       } else {
         document.getElementById("displayNumber").innerHTML = input.toString(2);
       }
     }

     display();

   </script>
 </html>
```

Comment: if I want to make use of the other functions, how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated snippet :

```js
  function check(input) {
   let quotient = [];
             while (input != 0) {
                 if (input < 1000 && input % 2 != 0) {
                     input = input / 2;
                 }
                 else if (input < 1000 && input % 2 == 0) {
                     input = input / 2;
                 }

                   quotient.push(input);
             }
             return quotient;

         }
 
         function display() {
             let input = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number between 1 and 1000", "50"));
             var answer = check(input);
             document.getElementById("displayNumber").innerHTML = answer;         

        }          
        display();
```

```html
 <h1 id="displayNumber"></h1>
```

Comment: If i wanted to add one more function, could I make it so I have a function with the array? How would I call it from there though?

Comment: You can make numbers of functions if you can and added as per requirements

Answer (score 0):

In display function, you are assigning **answer** to **innerHTML** but not calling your **check** function.

```
<html> 
    <h1 id="displayNumber"></h1>
    <script>
        let input = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number between 1 and 1000', '50'));
        function check(input) {
            let quotient = [];
            while (input > 0) {
                quotient.push(input % 2);
                input = parseInt(input / 2);
            }
            return quotient.reverse().join('');
        }

        function display() {
            if (input >= 1 && input <= 1000) {
                document.getElementById("displayNumber").innerHTML = check(input);
            }
        }

    display();

</script>
</html>
```